# Nuget Twitter Bootstrap-Multi Select and Nuget Twitter Bootstrap-Select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, multi-select, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-multiselect

**Nuget Twitter Bootstrap-Multiselect** and **Nuget Twitter Bootstrap-Select**

Are they the same package? Or two seperate packages? I need the checkboxlist from Bootstrap-Multiselect, but the only package available on Nuget is Twitter Bootstrap-Select?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? And then post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are different packages.

`Bootstrap-select` is pointing at https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select and has a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap-select/).

`Bootstrap-Multiselect` is pointing at https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect and does not have a NuGet package.

`Bootstrap-Select` is a dropdown list but can be used as a multiselect list (just add `multiple` attribute to your `<select>`) like shown in http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/